# fadeOut -> fadeIn doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

JS code:

```
var forma = $('form#mali_oglas'),
    pomoc = $('div[role=pomoc]'),
    div = $('.mali_oglas_pomoc'),
    input = forma.find('input, textarea');   

    input.on('click', function(){
        var name = $(':input:focus').attr("name")
        pomoc.fadeOut('fast', function(){            
            div.find("[data-pomoc='" + name + "']").fadeIn('slow');            
            console.log(name);
        });
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="mali_oglas_pomoc">
    <div data-pomoc="name" role="pomoc">
        1Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi pretium, urna nec varius sollicitudin, erat urna accumsan sapien, vel interdum enim risus id mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora.
    </div>
    <div data-pomoc="body" role="pomoc">
        2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi pretium, urna nec varius sollicitudin, erat urna accumsan sapien, vel interdum enim risus id mi. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora.
    </div>.....    
</div>
```

CSS for the div in question:

```
div[role="pomoc"] {position: absolute; top: 45px; right: 0;width: 250px; display: none}
div[role="pomoc"]:first-child {display: block}
```

It is working, but a bit strange. First it is applying **display block** to the targeted div, then fading it out and fading in. What is going on?

Link:
http://jsfiddle.net/AY2B3/

Comment: post it on jsfiddle so we can have a look

Comment: Well, that's what you're telling it to do, right? Fade out all `div[role="pomoc"]` and then fade in the one where `data-pomoc=name`. jQuery needs to apply `display: block` in order to do the fade out, the element starts from 100% opacity to 0% opacity. I think you want to make the first `div` visible when the page loads and then change the shown `div` with JavaScript. However, you can't do that with `:first-child`, you need to make the first `div` visible with JavaScript.

Comment: Of course it will apply `display: block` to the targeted `div` because `fadeIn` mostly works with `opacity`. Of course if fades out and then fades in, this is written in you code, isn't it?

Comment: In other words, it'd help if you described what you *want* it to do instead of letting us guess what you wanted to achieve with your code.

Comment: I want to fade out current visible element, and when it is over to fade in requested div. Added link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fadeOut callback is fired once for each completed animation.  In your example, the callback gets executed multiple times because pomoc contains multiple elements. The strangeness is probably a visual artifact related to calling fadeIn multiple times on the same element.

Comment: I'm new to jQuery, but the docs mention a combination of .promise() and deferred.done() as a means to get a single callback (http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn).

Comment: pomoc.fadeOut('fast').promise().done( function(){            
            div.find("[data-pomoc='" + name + "']").fadeIn('slow');            
        });